# Составить программу для подсчёта количества положительных элементов в массиве basic

Tags: visual-basic

```
Sub Main
    a=Dim (1 to 8) as string
    b=0
    i=0
    Ubound(A)(i)
    Do
        If A(i)>0 Then
        b=b+1
        end if
        i
End Sub
```

Где-то явно ошибаюсь в программе

Comment: `a` и `A` - одинаковые переменные? `A(i)>0` - строка сравнивается с числом - какой ожидается результат?

Comment: slippyk да, опечатался, переменные одинаковые. Результат, как я понял, - последующее увеличение вводимого числа

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так должно быть: [здесь можно проверить](https://onlinegdb.com/BycrhFTpN)

```
Sub Main()
    Dim numbers as Integer() = {0, -5, -9, 35, 1, 2, 4, 8}  ' искомый массив '
    Dim index as Integer
    Dim positive as Integer  ' счетчик положительных чисел '

    positive = 0
    For index = 0 To UBound(numbers)
        If numbers(index) > 0 Then
            positive = positive + 1
        End If
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(positive.ToString)
End Sub
```